# Where to ask question about licenses?

Tags: support, licensing, creative-commons

I typed **Code under MIT documentation under CC** as title of my question on Stackoverflow.

The suggestions popped up showing all licensing questions as closed.
Where shall the questions about licensing be asked?

My original question is:

> Why some project code is licensed under MIT and documentation under CC?
>
> For example [Font awesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/license/)

Comment: You can also post this kind of thing on [opensource.se].